# SQL Select top parentId on a list of Id's and return row if all same top parentId

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have to script i would like to combine in to one:

```
SELECT [CategoryId] FROM [dbo].[Unit] where Id in (716,724)
```

and

```
DECLARE @Id INT = 15

;WITH cteGetRootID
As
(

    SELECT
        Id, [Name], ParentId, 1 AS CodePosition
    FROM
        Category WHERE Id = @Id
    UNION All
    SELECT
        ic.Id, ic.[Name], ic.ParentId, CodePosition + 1
    FROM Category ic
    INNER JOIN cteGetRootID cte ON ic.Id = cte.ParentId
)
SELECT  top 1 Id, [Name]  FROM cteGetRootID
ORDER BY CodePosition desc
```

I would like to do low code for all result in first part and return Root Catogry if all have same Root
Like DECLARE @Id INT = SELECT [CategoryId] FROM [dbo].[Unit] where Id in (716,724)

Hope it make sence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `join` between `dbo.Unit` and `dbo.Category` in your first select of the union:

```
;WITH cteGetRootID
As
(
    SELECT
        c.Id, c.[Name], c.ParentId, 1 AS CodePosition
    FROM
        Category c 
            INNER JOIN  [dbo].[Unit] u on u.CategoryID = c.Id
    WHERE u.Id in (716,724) 
    UNION All
    SELECT
        ic.Id, ic.[Name], ic.ParentId, CodePosition + 1
    FROM Category ic 
             INNER JOIN cteGetRootID cte ON ic.Id = cte.ParentId
)
SELECT  top 1 Id, [Name]  FROM cteGetRootID
ORDER BY CodePosition desc
```